# Нахождение произведения отрицательных элементов матрицы

Tags: c++

Программа должна находить произведение отрицательных элементов матрицы.

Переменная dob Всегда выводит 1
https://pastebin.com/sKQ4cvGT

```
// ConsoleApplication7.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//Знайти добуток негативних елементів кожного рядка для матриць a(10,15) і b(15,12). Використовувати функцію.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
long dob = 1;

void atMat(int** &m, int row, int col) {
    m = new int*[row];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new int[col];
    }
}
//Ощичение памяти 
void reMat(int** &m, int row) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        delete[] m[i];
    }
    delete[] m;

}
//инициализация масива 
void inMat(int ** &m, int row, int col) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 100-50;
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int negativ(int **&m, int row, int col) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] > 0)
            {
                dob == dob * m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return dob;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int **arrayA = NULL;  // указатель на указатель 
    int ** arrayB = NULL;
    int aROW = 10;
    int aCOL = 15;
    int bROW = 12;
    int bCol = 10;
    arrayA = new int*[aROW];
    arrayB = new int*[bROW];

    atMat(arrayA, aROW, aCOL);
    atMat(arrayB, bROW, bCol);

    cout << "Your array a :" << endl;
    inMat(arrayA, aROW, aCOL);
    cout << "\n\n"; 
     cout << "Your array b :" << endl;
     inMat(arrayB, bROW, bCol); // инициализация масива и вывод на экран 

     cout << endl;
     cout << "dob negative elemet  massiva A ravno: " << negativ(arrayA, aROW, aCOL) << endl;
     cout << "dob negative elemet  massiva B ravno: " << negativ(arrayB, bROW, bCol)<< endl;

     reMat(arrayA, aROW); //очищение памяии
     reMat(arrayB, bROW);
     cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На будущее — не давайте ссылку на код, вставляйте его прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @Eanmos от наличия тут кода вопрос не станет лучше. Проблема не описана.

Comment: @alexolut, ну всяко лучше будет, хотя бы по ссылке переходить не надо.

Comment: @Eanmos надо править те вопросы, которые можно спасти, а тут портянка кода и "найдите ошибку". Код надо к виду [mcve] приводить сначала, так, глядишь, и проблема сама решится.

Comment: @alexolut, ну я же написал: «*На будущее*» :)

Comment: переменная dob Всегда равна 1

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh, если вы *действительно* хотите получить ответ на свой вопрос, вам следует пройти [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) и узнать [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ну а  C++ вы еще не проходили?...

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

```
int negativ(int **&m, int row, int col) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] > 0)
            {
                dob == dob * m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return dob;
}
```

Вы здесь сравниваете два числа, ничего не присваивая.

```
arrayA = new int*[aROW];
arrayB = new int*[bROW];

atMat(arrayA, aROW, aCOL);
atMat(arrayB, bROW, bCol);
```

А здесь два раза память выделяете. Уберите верхние две строчки.

Попробуйте вот так:

```
        if (m[i][j] < 0)
        {
            dob *= m[i][j];
        }
```

Ну и в самом начале функции `negativ` добавьте:

```
dob = 1;
```

Comment: *= Тоже самое что у меня в коде , пробовал по всякому не помагает

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh у вас в коде `dob == dob * m[i][j];`, обновил ответ

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh и знак в условии перепутан, у вас `if (m[i][j] > 0)`, а должно быть `if (m[i][j] < 0)`

Comment: знак я менял ,  у меня на каждой итерации выскакивают сейчас числа под 9 милиардов +-

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh разумеется выскакивают, переполнение же. Размер первого массива - 150. Допустим половина элементов массива - отрицательны, получаем 75 элементов. Допустим, все они равны -2 (реально от -1 до -50). `2^75=37778931862957161709568`

Comment: Не в этом дело там на  итерации такие числа выскакивают , и не важно какими числами запоняю массив

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh в смысле не в этом ? В `long` (4 байта) знаковый влезают числа от минус 2 миллиарда до плюс два миллиарда. Используйте длинную арифметику для умножения. Либо уменьшите размеры массивов до 10 хотя бы и используйте `long long dob`. Тогда в крайнем случае получим 50^10, что меньше чем 2^60, что влезает в 2^63 для знакового `long long`

Comment: Вопрос один зачем вы подносите к степени ? если нужно произведение ?

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh -2*-2*-2 (произведение трёх элементов) = -2^3, произведение 75-ти элементов равных -2 = -2^75. Если у вас из 75 элементов хотя бы 33 элементы меньше -1, то произведение 75 таких элементов будет ограничено снизу значением -2^33. Произведение N случайных отрицательных чисел в интервале от -1 до -50 (как у вас) по модулю ограничено снизу как 1, а сверху как 50^N.

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh я не то что подношу к степени, я пытаюсь оценить сверху и снизу возможное значение произведения. Это нужно чтобы правильно выбрать тип для хранения произведения чисел. Не всегда удаётся обойтись встроенными в C++ целочисленными типами данных.

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh о, и кстати, только сейчас увидел комментарий в самом начале кода в вопросе. Если я правильно понимаю, вам надо найти не произведение всех отрицательных чисел в массиве, а произведение всех отрицательных чисел каждой строки массива, тогда вы даже в long long должны поместиться с такими массивами.